# How can I make a node-steam admin?

Tags: javascript, steam

My admin code so far:

```
var admin = '76561198109313437';
var chatter;


bot.on('message', function(source, message, type, chatter) {
  // respond to both chat room and private messages
  if (message == 'dota2' && chatter == admin) {
    console.log("Now playing DotA2");
    bot.gamesPlayed([570]);
  }
});
```

I want the game to change only for the admins `steamid` but with this setup no-one at all can change it. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

```
bot.on('message', function(source, message, type, chatter) {
  // respond to both chat room and private messages
  if(message == 'dota2' && source == admin) {
    console.log("Now playing DotA2");
    bot.gamesPlayed([570]);
  }
});
```

The chatter was the problem, I should have set the value to source not chatter.